# Javascript ES6 TypeError in Safari & IE

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6, typeerror, polyfills

I am working with a Javascript code written by someone else who used ES6 in a Wordpress site. It makes an Ajax call to show a data in DOM, which works for Chrome and Firefox but for some reason Safari gives following error in console:

```
TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(".js_zip-lookup__submit").forEach is not a function. (In 'document.querySelectorAll(".js_zip-lookup__submit").forEach(function(e){e.addEventListener("click",function(){displayResults(e.parentNode.querySelector(".zip-lookup__input").value)})})', 'document.querySelectorAll(".js_zip-lookup__submit").forEach' is undefined)
```

This is the function:

```
function finderInit(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.js_zip-lookup__submit').forEach(function(button){
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
      const zip = button.parentNode.querySelector('.zip-lookup__input').value;
      displayResults(zip);
    });
  });

  document.querySelectorAll('.zip-lookup').forEach(function(form){
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      const zip = form.querySelector('.zip-lookup__input').value;
      displayResults(zip);
    })
  });
}
```

And I can't quite tell why Safari would have an issue with this, while Chrome/FF doesn't even log any error about this particular part in the console and it works just fine. I know it should be some browser compatibility issue but haven't found much information so far.

Comment: What version of Safari does this fail on?

Comment: @AndrewLi, actually it does [NodeList#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility) but it might not be in all browsers. Amma what version of Safari did you test this in? It seems it might or might not be supported in versions prior to Safari 10

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ahh yes. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You're correct, it works in Safari 10 but still has TypeError logged in console. And the functionality completely breaks down from Safari 9 below. I'm using Browserstack beside my own Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many variations of Array.prototype, but the only thing that solved IE & Safari compatibility issue was inclusion of this polypill snippet below, solution found in [this blog](http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/01/06/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-foreach/):

```
(function () {
    if ( typeof NodeList.prototype.forEach === "function" ) return false;
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns `NodeList` object, not an array. As it [can be seen on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Browser_compatibility), `NodeList` has `forEach` method but it's not well-supported, that's why it works in recent Firefox and Chrome but not in other browsers (Safari):

> Although NodeList is not an Array, it is possible to iterate on it using forEach().  Several older browsers have not implemented this method yet.

To iterate over node lists and other iterators in a compatible way, `Array.from` should be used (can be polyfilled in older browsers):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".js_zip-lookup__submit")).forEach(...);
```

Comment: That did remove TypeError and it works in Safari 10 but not for 9 and below. Is there any alternative for this to override compatibility? And also for IE if possible?

Comment: As it was said, Array.from is polyfillable. Use polyfills, e.g. https://github.com/zloirock/core-js. This should be done by default in any web project.

Comment: For those that may come across this in the future, ideally `core-js` would polyfill `.forEach` here too, but we'll see. https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/329

Comment: Actually core-js@2.4.1 has been included in this project already as a part of babel package, but still no .forEach polyfill...

Comment: @Amma The issue that loganfsmyth cited says that NodeList forEach polyfill is not there yet. Use Array.from, as the answer suggests.

Comment: I see. But Array.from doesn't solve issue for Safari 9 below and IE, only Safari 10 works with it.

Comment: It certainly does, that's why it was suggested. You can check that [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/rPNaWQHrtsgD9uv2zw8P?p=preview) is workable in any reasonable browser. If you still have problems with your case, consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Estus, older versions of Safari do not implement `.forEach` on nodelist objects. However, `Array.prototype.forEach` is defined as generic in the [ES5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) specifiction:

> The forEach function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the forEach function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.

Hence a workable solution is to call `Array.prototype.forEach` on the nodelist and pass it the function you want to execute. As a cut down (and cheap) test case:

```js
var col = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
//col.forEach(                    function (el) {document.write(el.id)});
Array.prototype.forEach.call(col, function (el) {document.write(el.id)});
```

```html
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
<p id="p3"></p>
<p id="p4"></p>
```

This was tested and found to work in Safari 5.1.7 for Windows and under Internet.  Explorer 9 emulation. The commented out line reproduces the error reported in the post in Safarai 5.1.7.

Comment: Thanks @Traktor. I used following code, and still not good for IE inside Browsertack. Any alternatives?  var zipSubmit = document.querySelectorAll('.js_zip-lookup__submit');   Array.prototype.forEach.call(zipSubmit, function(button){
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
      const zip = button.parentNode.querySelector('.zip-lookup__input').value;
      displayResults(zip);
    });
  });

Comment: Hard to say without error details and HTML code. If Browserstack is not helpful, try testing on a windows machine running IE with dev tools open (F12). Change the emulation mode to test older browsers.  If nothing shows up, write a for loop to add the event listeners and prove the rest of the code works. `.forEach` is ES5.1 and won't work in IE8 or earlier.